# Creating a column based on conditional values in R

Tags: r, conditional-statements

Trying to add a new binary column to a dataset that will return a "1" if it meets certain requirements (below) and a "0" if not.

```
(x == "1") & (width < 1 | width > 5 | height < 1.5 | height > 3.5)
```

Any idea how to do this??

Comment: Including a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) in your question will increase your chances of getting an answer.

Comment: Fix what exactly? Do you get an error of some sort? Unexpected output? You should provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output to make it more clear what exactly you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

a reproducible example is the best way to get an exact answer for your needs. but I would do something like..

```
library(dplyr)

df2 <- df %>%
       mutate(new_column = ifelse(width > 5, 1, 0))
```

`ifelse` works like `ifelse(expression, value_if_true, value_if_false)` and the expression must resolve to `TRUE` or `FALSE`.

This should also work:

```
df2 <- df %>%
       mutate(new_column = ifelse(((x == "1") & (width < 1 | width > 5 | height < 1.5 | height > 3.5)), 1, 0)
```